# Magento : How to Change Copyright in Footer

Tags: magento-1.9, footer, websites, copyright

I am trying to change copyright on my website from 2011 to 2011-2017. I have gone through `system/configuration/design/footer/copyright` and have attempted to change it with no luck. I have tried to go through files of my website but I have no which file footer would be in.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the copyright is added from backend you can change from below.

```
System -> Configuration -> General -> Design -> footer
```

However it may be possible if you are using any custom theme it may be defined in some other way.

You can check by going to

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/page/html/footer.p‌​html
```

If you still cant find the file. Open template hint from backend and check the footer file and from where the code is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this from the backend, go to System -> General -> Design and find it under the tab Footer.

Comment: I had tried that and the copyright would not change on the frontend. I also cleared out the cache after changing it. It is showing up as changed in the backend but is not appearing to have been changed in the frontend,

Comment: OK. The template should be located at `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/footer.phtml`, maybe you can check there.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it is saying to not edit the file and nothing about changing the copyright year. Again thank you very much for taking the time to help. If you have any other suggestions I will be open to try them.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System -> Configuration -> Design -> Footer

& then add "&copy yourwebsite.com 2011-2017

Answer (score 0):

Hello Here is the module after installing you just need to set the given value after every year values change automatically. It will set the current variable automatically.

after adding the following line footer setting copyright text shows like
[image]

```
'Copyright {{date_Y}} '
```

**https://github.com/niraligajera/copyright**